# Cannot load expo dev app on real device: There was a problem loading the project

Tags: android, react-native, expo, revenuecat

I'm trying to implement RevenueCat In-App Subscriptions into my Expo managed app, and to test the implementation I need to do it on a real device.

So far, I ran:

```
expo install expo-dev-client
expo install react-native-purchases
eas build --profile development --platform android
```

I downloaded the development build and installed it on the device, then I ran:

```
expo start --dev-client
```

After starting the dev server, it isn't visible on the development build I installed on the real device - I also tried manually adding the local address to the server, however I get the same error:

```
There was a problem loading the project. This development build encountered the following error. 
failed to connect to /192.168.1.187 (port 8081) from /192.168.1.133 (port 52184) after 10000ms
```

I need to mention that I've successfully installed the development build inside the Android emulator and I was able to connect to the dev client on it (I cannot test RevenueCat implementation here).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out the solution to the mentioned problem, so if you're unable to connect to expo dev client using your Android device, make sure to disable your Windows Firewall, that fixed the issue!